# "This is commentary on another post" too confusing. Can we add "too brief" answer deletion reason?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

I often meet very short answers in low quality queue such as:

- have you tried X? / try X->Y
- Z->V is what you're looking for
- blagvf(XJF.SDFJ_F, 20)

The most appropriate delete reason is probably:

> **This is commentary on another post, not an answer**
>
> “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
>   - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.”

The problem is, that sometimes such answers **do provide an answer**. The problem here is, that they give absolutely no explanation why `X-Y` will work or what is `blagvf` method, and why it needs constant `XJF.SDFJ_F`. Nevertheless, the auto-comment is too confusing, and the APs are protesting:

> Not an answer? But it **is** an anser.

Would it be a problem just to add **too brief for our quality standards** delete reason for such answers?

### edit

As Szymon's answer states, such answers should not be deleted at all, as long they answer the question in some way. Actually, it's what I'd prefer to do with such answers, and now I have support it's the right action.

Comment: The use of "anser" seems to reflect the quality of their contributions...

Comment: I've always taken that reason to be for answers of the from "Answer X is wrong because ....."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answers that are on topic and give a solution are still answers. They may deserve a downvote but shouldn't be converted to a comment or removed just because of their brevity. They may still be useful even if they are not great.

It's the quality not length that matters. I've seen longish answers that don't explain anything and do not contain anything useful. Again, a downvote is appropriate.

Another problem with judging answers on their length (or lack of it) is that it's quite subjective. What is a long enough answer for one person may be too short for another.

Introduction of some sort of objective minimum answer length wouldn't work as posters might just add some non meaningful fluff to fill the space.

Comment: Does it mean, that "have you tried `fkd()`?" is a valid answer and should never be voted to delete?

Comment: It should be downvoted first. It can be then voted to be deleted when its score is low enough. But it's all because of its lack of quality not its length.

Comment: OK so why the posts land in low quality queue based on length?

Comment: @Lukasz because of the **probability** they are bad. If simply too short was a criteria then they'd never get to the queue,  they d be auto converter (which I think can happen if they contain a link)

Comment: Because they *are likely* to be not answers. That doesn't mean that *every* short answer should be removed. If you ask me for regex matching 4 digits and I reply just `\d{4}`, it's still a correct answer. Not a very good one but can provide a solution.

Comment: @Szymon OK understood, feature request canceled